# SSIS Project Deployment Model : Update Execute Package Task with dynamic package name

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I need to upgrade some old SSIS packages with `SQL Server Data Tools 2012`, as a `Project Deployment Model`. One of them is an `Execute Package Task`, so when it is upgraded it asks which other package is the child package. However, the `PackageName` specified in that `Execute Package Task` is set at runtime, with an `Expression`, so it can execute many different packages, depending the situation. But the `Project Conversion Wizard` doesn't allow multiple child package selection.

How can i upgrade that package properly ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do an upgrade is using `SSIS Upgrade Wizard in SQl Server Data Tools` for more information see this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/05/16/upgrading-packages-to-ssis-2012/)

Comment: That's what i did. However, it keeps the `Package Deployment Model` and converting to `Project Deployment Model` is a separate task. It's during this additional step that i got stuck